# What's the opposite of required valid user in .htaccess authentication

Tags: htaccess, apache

I'm familiar with password protecting files and directories using apache authentication. I am working on a site where I have two WordPress installs on the same domain. One WP install is in the root /public_html/ another one is in a sub directory. We do NOT want to merge the user database this is why we are using separate WP installs.

The issue is I want to password protect wp-login.php file on the main install, but not on the sub directory install.

I went ahead and added the following code to my .htaccess file in my public_html directory.

```
AuthName "Admins Only"
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType basic

<Files wp-login.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

The issue is that this code blocks it for both the main WP site and the sub directory wp-login.php file.

I was hoping if there is a way that I  can add in my /folder/.htaccess which will keep the other WP install  open for login by anyone.

Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I did further research. Basically, all I had to do was add "Satisfy Any" argument. So the main .htaccess file looked like the one I posted in my initial thread. Then for the specific folder, I created a new .htaccess file (/folder/.htaccess).

Then added this:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

Much thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431378/how-to-remove-htaccess-password-protection-from-a-subdirectory) on StackExchange